# OpenCV VideoWriter silently stops after a time

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

After writing videos successfully for awhile, VideoWriter will silently start creating only empty video files.

This is on a Raspberry PI 3

OpenCV 2.4.9

The following script illustrates the issue:
Here's a standalone script that illustrates the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/pyton

import cv2
import time
import numpy
import subprocess

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'MJPG')

allret = 0
f = numpy.ones((480,640,3), numpy.uint8)
h,w,c = f.shape
print h,w,c
counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1
    print "Iteration: ", counter
    time.sleep(0.1)
    writer = cv2.VideoWriter("test.avi", fourcc, 5, (w,h))
    for i in xrange(20):
        writer.write(f)
    writer.release()
    writer = None
    ret = subprocess.call(["avprobe","test.avi"])
    allret += ret
    print "FAILURES:", allret
    if allret > 5:
        break
```

After about 800 or so successful videos we then only get bad videos. Restarting the scripts starts the process over.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring memory, threads, disk space, number of open file handles and swap space as it runs?

Comment: Well, disk space is consistent since it is re writing the same file.  Swap is not used, memory is fine.  What I also notice is that if I double the length of the video generated, the same failure happens in half the iterations so the block is related to number of frames written.  Seems like a full queue or pipe not being cleaned up or something.

Comment: If I manually build the latest 2.4.13 this appears to work fine.  Will still bite those using the python-opencv package in the repo.